# Why does the function below log undefined to the console? Shouldn't it throw an error like a is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function first() {
   var a = "Hello";
   console.log( this.a );
}

first(); // undefined
```

Why does the function below log undefined to the console ? Shouldn't it throw an error like `a` is not defined ?

Comment: Property access does not throw an error, unless the object on which it is being accessed is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In non strict mode, `this` will refer to `window`, therefore `this.a` will equal to `window.a`.

Try this with `'use strict'` at first line.

```js
// Original
function first() {
  var a = "Hello";
  console.log(this == window)
}
first();

// Strict example
(function(){
  'use strict'
  function first() {
    var a = "Hello";
    try {
      console.log(this.a)
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e.message)
    }
  }
    first();
})();

// Class-like example
function First() {
  this.a = "Hello";
  console.log(this.a)
  return this
}

new First();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said **a is not defined** it will mean that it is `undefined`. Whenever, you try to access property from an object and if the object does not exist then the error will be thrown, however, if the property does not exist, then undefined will be returned.

In the said example, try and run in browser console and log `this`, it points to `window` object. Hence, `this.a` will try to access the property from window object, which not found will return `undefined`.

```js
var a = "Hi";

function first() {
  var a = "Hello";
  console.log(this.a)
}
first(); // Hi
```

**Error scenario**

```js
function first() {
  var a = "Hello";
  console.log(obj.a) // throws error
}
first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use **this** instead of **var**.

```
function first() {
    this.a = "Hello";
    console.log(this.a);
}
first(); // "Hello"
```

If you want to create variable in the scope of object **first**, then modify the code like

```
function first() {
    this.a = "Hello";
    this.b = function() {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
}
obj = new first;
obj.b();
```

Comment: This would create variable inside of `window` object, that is probably not desired.